# How to get list of figures in Asciidoc

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor

I am using asciid for an article. In the end of my document I want to have a list of figures. How to I create a list of figures? Did not find something useful in the documentation for me.

Comment: Which implementation (asciidoc or asciidoctor?)

Comment: asciidoctor. Thought both support same syntax anyway. Is this not true?

Answer (score 2):

Nope there isn't one at the time of answer. I checked the docs (which you indicated you did as well) and I also grepped the codebase. There is good news though! You should be able to do this with an [extension](http://asciidoctor.org/docs/user-manual/#extensions).

Extensions can be written in any JVM language if you're using asciidoctorj, or in Ruby if you're using the core asciidoctor (I'm not sure about JavaScript for asciidoctorjs). You'll need to create two extensions probably: a TreeProcessor extension to go through the whole AST looking for images and pulling them out into a storage structure. Then you'll also need to create either an inline or block macro to actually place it within the page.

I strongly recommend examining the [API](http://asciidoctor.org/rdoc/Asciidoctor.html) for the nodes and functions you'll want to make use of. There are some other [examples of processors](https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-extensions-lab/tree/master/lib) that may also be helpful to examine.